# Geoserver "Layer Groups" with Raster Layer

Tags: raster, geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I need to group multiple geotiff raster layers together. Each layer works well on its own when being previewed through the "Layer preview" utility.

However, when I group the layers together through the "Layer Groups" utility, the created grouped layer is previewed as an empty/white layer.

I am a bit suspicious that the problem lies in the coverage band details (palette_index). I am a web developer who is trying to integrate the layers in a website and therefore I don't have an experience in what does the coverage band details exactly mean.

I am attaching the configuration screen of two of the tiff files I am referring to.

[image]

[image]

Update 1:
I have now pasted the geoserver log, does this show a memory related issue? One line says: 2015-10-25 06:02:42,864 ERROR [geotools.map] - Call MapContent dispose() to prevent memory leaks. You can view the log of 1000 lines here: http://jpst.it/CFPL

Comment: Could you check your `geoserver.log` for a relevant log message? You may be hitting a memory limit for example.

Comment: I have now added a log file, could you please check if this means a memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem for single tif files. If there are multiple tif files in the directory using the **ImageMosaic plugin** works without problems. To get rid of the error

> ERROR [geotools.rendering] - Argument "bgColor" should not be null.

I just had to **adjust the InputTransparentColor** (FFFFFF) for the layers that are part of the grouplayer:

[image: InputTransparentColor]

The **plugin is not able to handle single tif files!** I did not find similar configuration possibilities for WoldImages.
There are two workarounds I can think of to make use of the ImageMosaic plugin for a single tif:

- You could create a second tif (copy) with the exact same extents like the first and create a tfw file that makes the copy tif a neighbor of the original tif. Since the content is not relevant you could just use a complete white tif for that. (The layer boundingbox coordinates can be adjusted to just match the original tif afterwards)
- The second option would be to split the tif in multiple tif files.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error saying `Argument "bgColor" should not be null.`

There is no background colour argument in your request as it is received by the server (you can see this in the logs). Are you using the built-in later preview for your request?

As a temporary work around, can you try adding an explicit background colour in your request, even though this shouldn't be necessary: `bgcolor=0xffffff`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check a different approach.
Try using the ImageMosaic plugin if the geotiff file are coherent (e.g. an aerial mosaic).

See [this link](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html) for an intro.

Answer (score 0):

I had this [same problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214745/bgcolor-problem-on-cascaded-wms-grouplayer/221437#221437) on cascaded WMS layers. An upgrade to the [latest GeoServer 2.8](http://geoserver.org/release/2.8.x/) was helpful for me, the problem with `bgColor should not be null` seeem to be resolved there.