# bgcolor problem on cascaded WMS grouplayer

Tags: geoserver, wms, group-layer

On GeoServer I have two layers, both cascading a remote WMS. Both layers work fine in the layer preview.

Now I am putting both into one group layer and open the preview, which shows an empty response. When trying to query the group layer in the browser with

> localhost:8080/geoserver/ws/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&layers=ws:layername&styles=&bbox=6.03777,48.898,14.703518328104952,54.93599775300893&width=768&height=535&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/png&

I get the following response:

> Rendering process failed Argument "bgColor" should not be
>   null.

When I add `&bgColor=0xFFFFFF` to the request, I still get the same error response.

The same happens, when I call the underlying layers within the `layers` parameter, without using the group layer.

I thought, it might be about different WMS implementations on the remote WMS side, but even when I switch to different remote WMS services, the problem persists.

When Googling, I didn't find a response that seems to solve the problem. Do I miss something?

**UPDATE**

The WMS services I am using are

- http://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/adv_dop, layer mv_dop
- https://geodienste.sachsen.de/wms_geosn_dop-rgb/guest, layer sn_dop_020

Comment: can you share the WMS you are cascading so we can test?

Comment: @iant Yes, of course. I added the WMS as update to the question. Thanks.

Comment: For Info the WMS 1.1.1 spec (section 6.2.2) says that a GET request has the following syntax ` http://host[:port]/path?{name[=value]&}` so to specify bgcolor you would use `bgColor=0xFFFFFF&` and not `&bgColor=0xFFFFFF`. However bgcolor is optional and doesn't have to be specified (default is 0xFFFFFF). So if a service is requiring bgcolor then that would appear to be a bug.

Comment: @nmtoken What's the exact difference between `&bgColor=0xFFFFFF` and `bgColor=0xFFFFFF&`? The sense is just to separate parameters, no? I usually omit the ampersand after the last kvp for manual requests...

Comment: The exact difference is the location of the ampersand, which closes the name=value pairing.  Strictly speaking this means that all WMS 1.1.1 URLs should end in an ampersand.  The regex shows us that if we want to show a null value for bgcolor (to get the default) we should use bgColor& and not &bgcolor.  If we keep this in mind (that the ampersand comes at the end) then we'll end up with URLs like: `...wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&bgcolor&` rather than something like `...wms?&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&bgcolor`, but obviously specifications are there to be ignored

Comment: Six year later and this problem is still not solved. I'm in the same situation now. Two cascaded WMS layers, when grouped, the response is empty png.. sad:(
First layer: https://gis.starazagora.bg/geoserver/webmap/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=webmap%3AOrtho2020&bbox=438200.0%2C4655400.0%2C581250.0%2C4727770.0&width=768&height=388&srs=EPSG%3A7801&styles=&format=application/openlayers Second layer:
https://gis.starazagora.bg/geoserver/webmap/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=webmap%3AOrtho2021&bbox=438200.0%2C4655400.0%2C581250.0%2C4727770.0&width=768&hei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be a bug in my current GeoServer 2.8 installation. I upgraded to the [latest 2.8 build](http://geoserver.org/release/2.8.x/) and the request works now.